# How do I apply formatting to the parts of word.range?

Tags: vba, ms-word

The code below starts word application and should turn the text in MSWord, enclosed into double asterics into it's bold version. So the text `"this is **important**` should become "this is **important**"

The code

```
Sub test()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim testDoc As Object
    Dim testString
    
    testString = "this is something **important** and **this** is not"
    
    'the code that initialized Word
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    Set testDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    
    'parsing the range
    testDoc.Range.Text = testString
    parse testDoc.Range

End Sub

Private Sub parse(parseRange As Word.Range)
    Dim workRange As Word.Range
        
    'counter
    Dim i
    'position of opening asterics
    Dim pos
    'position of closing asterics
    Dim pos2
    'auxilary range
    Set workRange = parseRange.Duplicate
    
    i = 1
    'parse bold (**)
    'do while doulbe asterics can be found in string
    Do While InStr(i, parseRange.Text, "**") <> 0
        
        'define the position of opening and closing asterics
        pos = InStr(parseRange.Text, "**")
        pos2 = InStr(pos + 2, parseRange.Text, "**")
        
        'remove asterics
        parseRange.Text = Replace(parseRange.Text, "**", "", , 2)
        'setting the auxilary range to make it bold
        workRange.SetRange pos - 1, pos2 - 2
        workRange.Bold = True
    Loop
End Sub
'Result: only the word "this" is formatted.
```

The problem with this as I understand is that bold formatting belongs to the `workRange`, so when I change the starting and ending position of `workRange`, the bold formatting moves with it. How do I fix the code to work properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over complicating your solution. What you are looking to do is precisely what Find and Replace with wildcards is designed to do. Try this:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wordApp As Object
    Dim testDoc As Object
    Dim testString
    
    testString = "this is something **important** and **this** is not"
    
    'the code that initialized Word
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If wordApp Is Nothing Then
        Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    Set testDoc = wordApp.Documents.add
    
    'parsing the range
    testDoc.Range.text = testString
    FindReplaceWithWildcards testDoc, "(\*{2})(*)(\*{2})"

End Sub

Sub FindReplaceWithWildcards(docTarget As Document, findText As String)
   Dim findRange As Word.Range

   Set findRange = docTarget.Range

   With findRange.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .text = findText
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = True
      .MatchWildcards = True
      With .Replacement
         .ClearFormatting
         .text = "\2"
         .Font.Bold = True
      End With
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Does your code contain 2 nested `With` blocks? I thought it's invalid.